# Low-priority I/O in OS X

Tags: macos, io, scheduling

`launchd` has option to [run process with low priority I/O](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist). How does it work exactly? (how low is low, does it affect all operations?)

Is there an API that enables low priority I/O in applications not launched via `launchd`?

I need to scan watched (FSEvents) directories in background application, and I'd like this to be as gentle as possible.

Alternatively, how can I check if system/disk is busy doing I/O?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launchd uses `setiopolicy_np` ([man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/setiopolicy_np.3.html)), as can be seen in the source code [here](http://launchd.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/launchd/src/launchd_core_logic.c).

The standard `FSEvents` APIs explained in [this Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is gentle enough, so you don't have to care. It only tells you the fact that something in a watched directory is changed.

If you really tap into `/dev/fsevents` and get raw data, you need to be very careful not to overwhelm the system.

Comment: I use FSEvents. It does say when directory changes, but then I have to scan that directory, sometimes recursively (when FSEvents coalesces or drops events). `setiopolicy_np` looks perfect!